# Do Until Loop Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create "Do Until" loop in Excel VBA where it copies each value populated in column A of "SQL" worksheet (starting in cell A2), pastes the value into cell "A2" of the "Home" worksheet, runs the "PDF" macro that already exists, continues this process for each populated value, and ends when there are no more values in column A of "SQL" worksheet. I'm very new to VBA, and tried coming with something from other posts/blog. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Dim rngMyRange As Range, rngCell As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim SheetName As String


With Worksheets("SQL")
Set rngMyRange = .Range(.Range("a2"), .Range("A1000").End(x1up))

Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(rowNo, 1))
  For Each rngCell In rngMyRange
  rngCell.Cells.Select
  Selection.Copy
  Sheets("HOME").Select
  Range("A2").Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Application.Run "'PDF Generator.xlsm'!PDF"

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: So what's the problem? There is no question in this post. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

You have a for loop inside the Do loop.  Remove the Do loop.

You never use `End With`

Also avoid the use of `.Select` and `.Activate` it slows the code:

```
Dim rngMyRange As Range, rngCell As Range


With Worksheets("SQL")
    Set rngMyRange = .Range(.Range("a2"), .Range("A1048576").End(xlup))
End With

For Each rngCell In rngMyRange
  rngCell.Copy
  Sheets("HOME").Range("A2").PasteSpecial
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Application.Run "'PDF Generator.xlsm'!PDF"
Next rngCell
```

Comment: Hi Scott - Thank you for your help! I'm wondering if you may know a better way for me to define the range. I'm getting an application defined or object defined error. My range will vary day to day, and it will be based on the number of populated rows in column A of the "SQL" worksheet, beginning in cell "A2".

Comment: On which line are you getting the error?  also see edit I made it look beyond the 1000th row.

Comment: It points to the whole range line when I debug.    Set rngMyRange = .Range(.Range("a2"), .Range("A1048576").End(x1up))

Comment: Missed you had a typo on `x1up` should be `xlup`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Add a dot here:

```
Do Until IsEmpty(.Cells(rowNo, 1))
```

Without the dot it is refering to the activesheet.