# excel vba sum multi sheet got run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: .net, vba, excel, sum, runtime-error

I got this 1004 run-time error on the code below. The line I mark as comment is the key of this question. Whenever the line mark as comment this code always got 1004 run-time error. And the code works good when I put the line back as normal code. Is there anyway to skip the sheet activation during this code since that activation makes the excel jumping around during the code running.

Thank you.

```
Public Sub Summary_calculation()

   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim endrow As Integer
   Dim temprow As Integer
   Dim tempcol As Integer
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim totalrec As Integer
   Dim tmpSheet As Worksheet
   Dim SKUCol As Integer
   Dim SKUName As String
   Dim tmpSheetrow As Integer
   Dim tmpcol As Integer
   Dim tmpQty As Double

   Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
   Set ws = wb.Sheets("Summary")

   SKUCol = 3

   totalrec = ws.Cells(startrow, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1

   For i = 1 To totalrec

      SKUName = ws.Cells(i + startrow, SKUCol).Value

      Set tmpSheet = wb.Sheets(SKUName)

      'tmpSheet.Activate (Got 1004 error whenever remove this line of code)

      tmpSheetrow = tmpSheet.Cells(startrow, Gapcol).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + startrow - 1

      For tmpcol = 0 To 16
         With wb.Sheets(SKUName)

            ws.Cells(i + startrow, tmpcol + 4).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range(Cells(startrow + 1, PropStartcol + tmpcol), Cells(tmpSheetrow, PropStartcol + tmpcol)))

         End With
      Next tmpcol
      ws.Cells(1, 10) = Format(i / totalrec, "00%")
      DoEvents
   Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try :

1. to replace `Set wb = ActiveWorkbook` by `Set wb = ThisWorkbook`
2. to put your code in a new module

`ThisWorkbook` refers to the workbook where you execute your code.
Error 1004 can happen when you have other workbook open.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
ws.Cells(i + startrow, tmpcol + 4).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range(Cells(startrow + 1, PropStartcol + tmpcol), Cells(tmpSheetrow, PropStartcol + tmpcol)))
```

Write this:

```
ws.Cells(i + startrow, tmpcol + 4).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range(.Cells(startrow + 1, PropStartcol + tmpcol), .Cells(tmpSheetrow, PropStartcol + tmpcol)))
```

The difference is the dot in front of Cells (twice in the code). Without the dot, the `Cells` take as its worksheet the activesheet or the sheet in which they are located. And it breaks, because `.Range()` takes `wb.Sheets(SKUName)`.

This is probably the most common problem in StackOverflow for [vba](/questions/tagged/vba):

- ['With Worksheets("xxxx")' works only when "xxxx" is the active worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48382421/with-worksheetsxxxx-works-only-when-xxxx-is-the-active-worksheet/48382702#48382702)
- [Find last column & sort on last column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49238125/find-last-column-sort-on-last-column/49238344#49238344)
- [Variable not being stored in the code when sheet changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50465500/variable-not-being-stored-in-the-code-when-sheet-changes/50465557#50465557)
- [How to set up vba code for only one sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50758680/how-to-set-up-vba-code-for-only-one-sheet/50758824#50758824)
- [Finding and deleting last column with header if sum is 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48463874/finding-and-deleting-last-column-with-header-if-sum-is-0/48463998#48463998)
- [Do Until Loop Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45886700/do-until-loop-excel-vba/45886736#45886736)
- [Append Worksheets of same structure from multiple Excel Files into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49796422/append-worksheets-of-same-structure-from-multiple-excel-files-into-one/49796488#49796488)